# Partial least squares regression (PLS regression): normalize for the number of inputs

Tags: regression, logistic, partial-least-squares

I am trying to do classification to separate two groups and try to extract important features by calculating variable importance using PLS. However, number of inputs are different. for instance for A condition I have 1300 and for B I have 3209. Shall I do kind of normalization to compensate for the different number of inputs, either after or before regression?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your data? Are these inputs are same? Let's say $var_1$ to $var_{100}$ for A and $var_{400}$ to $var_{600}$ for B. In that case not only the numbers but also the variables are different.

Comment: Also, if at least some of the variables are same, you can discard the unique ones. One can also try algorithms that can operate on missing data, but for PLS case I am not aware of any.

Comment: @theGD let say A1-A1300 and B1-B3209. they are not the same. in total 4509 entries (they are different genes belong to two different conditions). I have 80 features and I would like to calculate VIP to see which features have more important in separating these two sets (A and B) .